# Different Color Depth Between Windows and C#

Tags: c#, windows, colors

I have a gray-scale TIFF image which windows properties say its Bit-depth is 4 (which is supposed to mean it is 4 BPP), but when I open the image in C# as a bitmap the pixelFormat property says it is Format8bppIndexed (8 BPP), is it the bitmap constructor changing the pixel format or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TIFF format is an container (like ZIP). One TIFF file can contain various frames containing different files / data. An frame can be a bitmap. And each bitmap can have a different pixelFormat. A TIFF file can (or could) have a preview bitmap that has a different pixelFormat.

To get the actual pixelformat of the first frame you could use this :

```
    Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("file.tif", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

    PixelFormat pixelFormat = bitmapSource.Format;
```